# Clicking an image, trying to get the description to appear

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am making a little forum and on this forum I have a few different images. I would like to see if I can click on the image and have a short description of the image that the users clicked. I am having trouble seeing how to make this happen, this is what I have so far:

```html
<a class="desc" href="https://www.horizon-dawn.com/about">
    <img id="Horizon" src="https://image.api.playstation.com/vulcan/ap/rnd/202010/0221/vC7trMorHJgbImp8PCQvpI0p.png">
    </img>
</a>
```

This will make the image clickable and then once you click the image it always redirects me to `"This site can't be reached"` Error.
On the JavaScript file that I have linked to the HTML I have this line, which needs to be modified, but I would not know how to:

```
app.get("/about", (req, res) => {
    res.render("description", {
      description: "Horizon Zero Dawn is a 2017 action role-playing game developed by Guerrilla Games and published by Sony Interactive Entertainment. The plot follows Aloy, a young hunter in a world overrun by machines, who sets out to uncover her past. The player can explore the open world to discover locations and take on side quests."
    })
});
```

I am using node.JS and having the NPM express that I installed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much

Comment: what part are you not sure of? How to add an event listener with javascript?

Comment: Try giving relative path of /about file in the <a> tag. That might solve your "This site can't be reached" issue

Comment: Are you saying link the /about to the anchor tag in my HTML file @SalomiEdward. No, I have an event handler in JavaScript, what I am having trouble is having the other page that will be re-directed as users click on the image and having a short description display on that other page which I made https://www.horizon-dawn.com/about as the URL

Comment: This is what I have so far in terms of code. https://github.com/federicofloresta/Forum.git. Take in mind its still a work in progress, I thank you for any suggestions that can point me to the right direction. Will work on changing the app.render to app.send, but I would like to get one working properly after I tackle the other ones. Thank you for the assistance everyone that has time to help out!